# Flutter How to show colored Icon instead white color on flutter local notifications?

Tags: flutter, android-notifications

Good evening,
I'm building notifications with a color icon with that package Flutter_local_notification(https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)
The icon is showing white with a blue background color, but I see other applications showing color notifications icon

my app_icon images at this path:

android\app\src\main\res\drawable*

```
InitializationSettings settings = const InitializationSettings(
  android: AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon'),
  iOS: DarwinInitializationSettings(),
);
```

that's example for what I need to do too color image or icon
[image]

and that's what I get

[image]

Thanks in advance for everyone.

Comment: it is not possible due to system ui